# Audio not playing on all iOS devices

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, xcode4, avfoundation

I have an xcode (4.3.2) project where I am trying to play audio.  I have two iPad2 devices to test on.  Both are running iOS 5.1 (9B176), though one is a 3G and one is not.  The sound plays in the simulator and the none 3G iPad, but I can't get the audio to play on the 3G device.

Audio works on the programs I have on the device though.  The method I have for playing sound is as follows

```
-(void) playSound {
  NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gbm_menu_music"   
                                                       ofType:@"m4a"];
  NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
  avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:soundURL];
  [avPlayer play];
}
```

Which I call from

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Forgive me for stating the obvious but the iPad isn't muted is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was a problem specific to the device itself.  On the iPad in Settings under General, under the heading "Use Side Switch to:", the device was set to "Lock Rotation".  Changing it to "Mute" fixed the problem.  Switching it back to "Lock Rotation" is fine too.

Answer found at:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/610297#610297

Comment: If the side switch is used to mute the device and then later the side switch is changed to "lock rotation," the device can be left "muted" with no obvious way to unmute it. There is a way to do this without changing the side switch settings: bring up the multitasking thing by double-clicking home, swipe over to the left of the icons, and you should be able to tap on the speaker icon next to the volume slider to toggle mute.